# Firefox addon uninstall through registry

Tags: windows-registry, firefox, extension

I have installed a Firefox add-on by adding a key-value pair in the registry under the following path-

`Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\Install\1 = "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/myfile.xpi"`

The installation works

I want to uninstall the same extension, so I am adding another entry under the following path-
`Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\Uninstall\1 = "bad_addon_id@mozilla.org"`

I am using the appropriate id and path. I am getting the add-on id by clicking on debug add-ons in Firefox, under the extension id field under my extension. I think this is the right way to find the add-on id.

But the un-installation doesn't seem to be successful, I am still able to see the add-on in Firefox.
I tried this on various machines and add-ons. The result still being the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from the [documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#extensions) and it took me a while but the value of the key should be the extension id including the braces.

Example:
`{d4a5b766-4831-43f0-9d38-0fec359491e7}`

As an alternative you can also try [extension settings](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#extensionsettings) which enable more precise control of extensions in Firefox, like actually blocking the installation.

[image: Dialog box with blocked message]